# How can I save a value to localStorage in a dynamically generated jquery list, while also generating an href for each element?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

I am pulling a list of file names from my database and listing them dynamically with jquery. They are added to the html as an unordered list. I want each item to link to my details page, but also I need the file id to save to local storage on click. Is this possible? Do I just need work on my syntax? Any help is appreciated.

jquery function:

```
$(function() {
  var $files = $('#files');
  $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: 'some url',
      data: {},
      success: function(files) {
        $.each(files, function(i, file){
          $files.append('<a href="details.html" onclick="localStorage.setItem("file", +file.id+)";>'+file.id+'</a>');
        });
      },
      // Error handling 
      error: function (error) {
      console.log(`Error ${error}`);
      }
  });
})
```

HTML

```
<ul id="files"></ul>
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow! Please provide more complete code, otherwise we can only provide you with pseudocode to show you the answer.

Comment: @SeanKendle I added the whole function and the html call. That's about all I've got right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got double quotes inside of double quotes, and some random "plus" signs.

Change your code to this, to use a template literal instead:
(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

```
$files.append(`<a href="details.html" onclick="localStorage.setItem('file', '${file.id}')";>${file.id}</a>`);
```

Using string templates will allow you to directly print the value of a variable into the string with `${variableName}`

---

Oops, I misunderstood the question, leaving this answer on how to cache a list in localStorage in case someone needs it:

Before you pull from your database, see if it exists in local storage:

```
$(function() {
    let storedFiles = window.localStorage.getItem('stored_files');
    
    if(storedFiles !== null) {
        //found in local storage, use this:
        files = JSON.parse(storedFiles); //local storage is stored as a string, you have to convert back to an object
    
        //generate the list of files
        generateListOfFiles(files);
    } else { 
        // not found in local storage, get from database
        
        $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: 'some url',
          data: {},
          success: function(files) {
            //generate the list of files:
            generateListOfFiles(files);
    
           // now store the files back in local storage for next time!
           window.localStorage.setItem("stored_files", JSON.stringify(files)); // local storage should be stored as a string, as mentioned above
          },
          // Error handling 
          error: function (error) {
          console.log(`Error ${error}`);
          }
        });
        
        
    }

    function generateListOfFiles(files) {
        $.each(files, function(i, file){
            let $files = $('#files');
    
            $files.append('<a href="details.html" onclick="localStorage.setItem("file", +file.id+)";>'+file.id+'</a>');
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. I only want one file id to be saved at a time. So I can use it in my details.html page. The file id will only be saved to local storage when the link for that file is clicked on the files.html page. Right now it only saves as null value

Comment: I misunderstood, I thought you wanted to cache the list of files for the user to avoid a query to the database.

Updating my example

Comment: Updated my example

Comment: Learn about Template Literals, they're awesome!!

Comment: I'll check out Template Literals for sure, thanks. I accepted, but I don't have enough rep to upvote yet. I will definitely come back as soon as I get enough and upvote.